# What is the value of the complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> What is the value of
>
> $$\displaystyle\int_\gamma\frac{z^3e^{\sin\pi z}}{(z-1)^3}dz,~\gamma(t)=2e^{it},0\le t\le 2\pi$$

Comment: This seems like a straightforward application of Cauchy's integral formula. Did you try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, up to a constant $\frac{2!}{2\pi i}=\frac{1}{\pi i}$, the second derivative of $f(z)=z^3e^{\sin \pi z}$ at $1$. By virtue of Cauchy's differentiation formula:
$$
f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz
$$
which is basically [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), since $\gamma$ has winding number $1$ around $1$ and $f$ is entire.